# Watch file using multitail even if it has not been created

Tags: logs, multitail

I've a MapServer logfile; it is created in `/tmp/mapserv.log`, but obviously it is flushed at every reboot, and is created only when a loggable event occurs.

I'm already using Multitail, but now I need to watch the folder `/tmp` for a file that has not even been created, waiting for it to appear.

Any hint?

Comment: Could you `touch` it before starting multitail? (Edited Q)

Comment: Of course I could write a script or Bash alias to touch it before starting multitail, although I've never tried to run MapServer with an already present logfile (it should append results to it); I'm searching for a more "clean" solution or a specific multitail feature, but, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could perhaps use the `-iw` option. It check for new files matching a given
pattern at a given interval. When one is found start following it.

E.g.:

```
multitail -iw /tmp/mapserv.log 2
```

Would look for the file `/tmp/mapserv.log` every 2 seconds. If and when it 
appears follow it.

It is meant to take a wildcard as in

```
-iw "/tmp/map*" 2 
# Quotes needed to prevent the shell to expand the pattern.
```

but works for non-wildcard as well. The number is how often to check for new
files matching the pattern.

---

Else, `touch` could perhaps work. Might require something like `su user -c 'touch ...'` or a `chown` etc after touch.

If MapServer deletes existing `mapserv.log` on first logging and not truncate
or append you would perhaps also need the `-f` option, as in:

> Follow the following filename, not the descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

This is an OOOOLLLLD question, but the best answer has changed:

Use the `--retry-all` switch like this:

`multitail --retry-all file1.log file2.log [...]`

You should see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/multitail) for full details, but in short, all files after `--retry-all` are retried similar to `tail`'s `-F`/`--retry` switches.